# Beware of FrontBot Scamming!

Tags: uniswap, scam, bot

I was messing around YouTube and bumped into this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W5X5WdCVL3M&t=411s

Followed up all the things and gave a dumbass look into the code, nothing seemed suspicious until I tried to retrieve my funds. Immidiately after I noticed that the start function included a transfer to an address which was created by _callFrontRunActionMempool() function. Now, I've lost all my ETH and they're in this address: https://etherscan.io/address/0x2edbc4579042807310bdb11cfdd756c620dc5601

Here's the code of the script I'm talking about: https://pastebin.com/raw/4kkjRCSd

I did not sign the withdrawal but now my funds are stored in a smart contract. The thing I don't get how this is a scam is that I've created the address to send the funds all by myself. As I try to withdraw the funds, I get the following error:

**Gas estimation errored with the following message (see below). The transaction execution will likely fail. Do you want to force sending?
execution reverted: WARNING: not enough ETH for profitable frontrunning. Need at least 1 ETH at present market conditions. Cannot withdraw during an active trade, try again in about an hour...
{
"originalError": {
"code": 3,
"data": "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",
"message": "execution reverted: WARNING: not enough ETH for profitable frontrunning. Need at least 1 ETH at present market conditions. Cannot withdraw during an active trade, try again in about an hour..."
}**

Does anyone know a way to get them back, maybe by writing another script and retrieving the funds from the contract.

Update: It was a valuable lesson and a perfect example for **** around and find out. I've made deeper research on the topic and now able to at least understand the process. Lesson learned: Make sure that you fully understand any type of script before playing with it.

Comment: I sorry for your loss. To anyone else reading, one of the red flags in the code is the name of the function `_callFrontRunActionMempool` that you mention. A smart contract does not have any awareness of the mempool. All it sees is the state on the chain. Anyone should pause and think whether what they are claiming makes even slightest bit of sense or it's just a bunch of tech terms randomly thrown together.

Answer (score 6):

Oh my! Here we go again...

I've seen this 3 times already.

Look at my first answer:

[Missing Eth after sending to contract](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/134526/missing-eth-after-sending-to-contract/134529#134529)

My second answer:

[Got scammed using bad code to create front running bot](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/135077/got-scammed-using-bad-code-to-create-front-running-bot/135081#135081)

Short story, yes, unfortunately you got scammed.

As you experienced, the contract hides its intention by using weird and complicated logic and generates the scammer address dynamically so it does not look suspicious if it was hardcoded.

The scammer will be able to call the `withdrawal()` function and drain the balance of your contract. There's nothing you can do to recover your funds. If you call the `withdrawal()` function, you will be sending the eth to the scammer right away.

All the functions in that contract are `pure` (except the ones that receive eth, `start` and `withdral`). They are not doing anything really, they are not even reading from storage, they are not calling any other contract, they just have a bunch of logic that does nothing so you think it's doing something.

DON'T SEND ANY MORE ETHER TO THAT CONTRACT!