# Recover ETH in a smart contract

Tags: solidity, remix, ether, bsc, scam

I watched YouTube  tutorial  and deployed smart contract using solidity and remix. `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LDM9WphwRWc`

`https://rentry.co/erfex/raw`

But while I deploying the contract in Binance smart chain instead of Ethereum Mainnet and fund transferred to Etherium network.

Is there any way to withdraw money back to  metamask?

This is the created contract address 0xBE30fb3a6b5ec4A36d790ec89BB2460047a6e42e

Answer (score 3):

I've seen this too many times already. This is a scam, unfortunately, the funds are lost. Only the scammer can retrieve those funds.

I have explained this many times here. Take a look at this answer that mentions another answer that mentions another answer, etc., with details: [I Think I Got Scammed By Uniswap FrontRunner Scam Bot](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/135176/i-think-i-got-scammed-by-uniswap-frontrunner-scam-bot/135178#135178)

Basically, the scammer is dynamically generating an address that he owns, to then withdraw the funds of that contract. If you send funds to that contract, the funds will be sent automatically to the scammer. If there are funds in the contract now, don't try to send more eth, the scammer will be able to withdraw the eth in that contract, not you.

Comment: Nu uh, check my answer (:

Answer (score 3):

Wait wait wait, i started reading your question, and exactly like the 1st guy who answered i instantly stopped thinking and was like "oh yeah, it's that "frontrunner bot" scam again, the funds are lost anyways", but **NO**, you did not send any funds to the contract you deployed. You deployed the contracts on the BSC, but transferred the funds on ETH mainnet, **so you actually can recover the funds.**

Here's an explanation and a step by step guide :

- Explanation (you can skip that if you don't care) :
  When you deploy a smart contract, its address is computed using your address and the current transaction's nonce, so it is perfectly possible to deploy a contract at the same address on different networks. The contract you deployed on the BSC at address 0xBE30fb3a6b5ec4A36d790ec89BB2460047a6e42e was your 17th transction on that chain (https://bscscan.com/tx/0x7ddfb0f98c4b8a2a25eb95af74eac8aab8bb3a636a8394095d1e356d7188f904, here, you can see the transactions nonce is 16). That means if your 17th transaction on ETH mainnet is  a contract deployment, said contract will also be deployed at address 0xBE30fb3a6b5ec4A36d790ec89BB2460047a6e42e, (the address you sent funds to), and from there getting the funds back  is trivial. **VERY** luckily, you happen to have made 16 transactions on ETH mainnet with the address you deployed the scam contract from on the BSC ( here's your last mainnet tx https://etherscan.io/tx/0x06b31d60bafccf098a3a22f0e2ec886c91923dbd0a4081cc1f681ed2ff963e02 (deploying the scam contract again? x') ) . Meaning that your next tx, if it's a contract deployment, will deploy a contract at that address you sent funds to. Now onto the =>
- Step by step guide : Double check that your accounts nonce is indeed 16 (in metamask : settings => advanced => customize transaction nonce, that will make the tx s nonce show up in the transaction's confirmation screen, like so (**NEVER MODIFY IT UNLESS YOU'RE CERTAIN YOU KNOW WHAT YOU'RE DOING!** Here, we're using it for verification purposes only):

[image]

Now head over to remix, and deploy this contract (you already know how to deploy a contract, so no screenshots here ^^) :

```js
Contract GetMeMoneyBack {
    constructor() {
        // Using selfdestruct() is cheaper than simply sending the balance
        selfdestruct(payable(msg.sender));
    }
}
```

And boom, you got your money back :) (Remember, if this is not your 17th transaction (i.e., if the nonce is not 16), it WILL **NOT** WORK)

Comment: Thanks a lot Foxxey, I will try this and update you

Comment: fcken hell this is some genius insight , bravo foxxxey bravo

Answer (score 0):

@Jeremy [I Think I Got Scammed By Uniswap FrontRunner Scam Bot](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/135176/i-think-i-got-scammed-by-uniswap-frontrunner-scam-bot/135178#135178) Unanswer and reply the question with this suggestion below:

This man's funds are stuck in the contract and have not been sent to the scammer. So it's possible for him to retrieve his funds back by using a transfer payable at the contract address.

In Remix IDE, Instead of "Deploy" by creating a new contract in the "DEPLOY & RUN OPERATIONS" section, you can access your old contract again by typing the old contract address you created in the "At Address" field and clicking the "At Address" button.
Note: Access cannot be made with any other account other than your metamask account where you created the contract.

function to run: payable(addressToMoveFundsTo()).transfer(address(this).balance)

Comment: That.. is not how smart contracts work, you can't just execute arbitrary logic like that. If it worked like that that would mean i could go to the WETH contract or whatever and transfer all the funds here to my address