# ETH from zkSYNK sent to wETH contract adress on Ethereum

Tags: ether, wrapped-tokens, zksync

Really curious if i could do something to retrive it.

I was on th WHOP website trying to pay for something and i didn t notice that i was on zkSYNK network and not on ethereum like i should have been. I signed a message to wrap ETH and apparently it wrapped the ETH from the zkSYNK . I will post the transaction that did this and another one that wraped ETH from ethereum network and a photo of both these transactions from debank. If there s anything i could do please do tell, i m willig to even give some eth to someone who helps me in sign of appreciation :)
https://explorer.zksync.io/tx/0x10e7c7a47473dc4b9dbcc814f859ad12d6534a7c75a2c37688c4315c97bf331c
https://etherscan.io/tx/0xb3e72841f05a8f08b31d8ea833f76523df3cbb61ed3ca6a5b4efa10edfb82a2f
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, no. You really just sent ETH to an address no one owns, there's no way to get it back. *Theorically*, if the deployer  of the WETH contract on ETH mainnet were to create a contract as its 447th transaction on zkSync, the contract would be deployed at address 0xC02aaA39b223FE8D0A0e5C4F27eAD9083C756Cc2, and assuming it's specifically crafted to do that, it would be able to give you your ETH back (see [this](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/136459/recover-eth-in-a-smart-contract/136472#136472)), but that's not going to happen, i guess.