# Recover ETH in Smart Contract

Tags: remix, ether, metamask

I'm reaching out to you because I think I've been scammed. I watched a video (`https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vv5l9VIBF1o`) on YouTube that claimed to show how to set up a bot to earn ETH. So, I followed the "tutorial" step by step.

However, when I checked my bot on Etherscan.io, I noticed that my Ether had disappeared...

Do you think it would be possible to recover them, or is it too late? I saw a response from Foxxxey on a post suggesting that it might be possible to deploy a new contract to retrieve the lost funds (on this post: [Recover ETH in a smart contract](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/136459/recover-eth-in-a-smart-contract)). Unfortunately, I can't seem to reach them.

Thank you in advance for your responses.

Have a good rest of your day.

Comment: I'm stuck I'm a similar situation. I sent my tokens to the wrong wallet and now they're stuck. Trying to figure out how to get them back.

Comment: The situation that Foxxey's answer solves is different. The victim deployed the scam contract in the BSC blockchain and sent the ether to Ethereum mainnet. If you used the same blockchain for both operations it cannot be recovered.