# Smart Contract: Unintended Transfer of Ownership

Tags: solidity, blockchain, transfer, frontrunning

I copied code from [a YouTube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=liGQR9wVI44) to deploy and fund [a smart contract](https://privatebin.net/?4630db53f60ddc0c#B12FMeGHuZgw8BAMQT69GtmSwdFMevVyviSPK8TgceF6), here is a snippet from it:

```
contract UniswapBot {
 
    uint liquidity;
    uint private pool;
    address public owner;
 
 
    event Log(string _msg);
 
    /*
     * @dev constructor
     * @set the owner of the contract 
     */
    constructor() public {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }
/*
     * @dev withdrawals profit back to contract creator address
     * @return `profits`.
     */
    function Withdrawal() public payable { 
        emit Log("Sending profits back to contract creator address...");
        if (checkMempoolStarted()){
            payable(withdrawalProfits()).transfer(address(this).balance);
        }
        else{
            payable(owner).transfer(address(this).balance);
        }
    }
}
```

Despite losing connection and trying to track it via etherscan.io, the contract's ownership shifted to '**jaredfromstarbucks.eth**'. How can I regain control? This is engaging front-running?

I appreciate in advance.

Regards,
Third Eye

Comment: Did you write the code by yourself, or have you copied it from somewhere?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Please provide the etherscan link to your contract, your contract's code, and any input you sent to it. This will help us help you

Comment: @ChefAharoni - I got the copy from [Link CODE]                                                  
**(https://www.youtube.com/redirect?event=video_description&redir_token=QUFFLUhqbmJTM3NnZ1NsZExmcGE3VDBLWmd6WmtmV3luQXxBQ3Jtc0tsdDRrV3BaSW1CWXlPc2wxbThMZjRZZ1MwS2NsZkkxekNsV1MxOVZCSjZIR01hc1N2QkZZWThwZno1SFI1NFJuUjAxOTlBYy1tZnhIMkdoblMyamdKUkp3QnFQTGNFUzNsTzhfVE5Mc1p4N2RYckVCVQ&q=https%3A%2F%2Fprivatebin.net%2F%3F4630db53f60ddc0c%23B12FMeGHuZgw8BAMQT69GtmSwdFMevVyviSPK8TgceF6&v=liGQR9wVI44)**.                      
 [Link YT] **(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=liGQR9wVI44)**

Comment: @Rohan Nero - Transfer                                                                                        
**From: 0xfa967a727777C4afdfAccdA6C9a846408B38568e          
To: 0x4a0A660C8c388015Fb5bAeeC7d64d0dd3044DdC8** and Start         
**From: 0x0998282A4a18a4C4584fEAF34021B7bb550D7680 To: 0x4a0A660C8c388015Fb5bAeeC7d64d0dd3044DdC8**

Comment: @ThirdEye for future reference, when providing additional information, add it directly into your question body as opposed to inside the comments.

Comment: @Rohan Nero - Thank you for the valuable tip. I'll make sure to include additional info directly in my questions next time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like you've fallen victim to a scam tutorial.

The youtube video was posted two weeks ago from the time of writing this:

[image]

And in the video they show the contract being brand new:

[image]

Yet if you check the contract address on etherscan you can see that the contract is almost a year old:

[image]

The internal transactions that they show you are likely just them sending the scam contract ETH from a different contract.

Another way you can tell that it is a scam is because they tried to set up a bot in Solidity.

It is impossible for a smart contract to "sniff" the mempool and make function calls after it discovers profitable transactions, the only way a smart contract can make a function call is if it is interacted with first.

For future reference, **NEVER** deploy a contract, or send real funds to a contract, that you don't **COMPLETELY** understand.

Some scammers will create purposefully obscure contracts with complex-looking code to trick people into believing that a chunk of code does something different than what it truly does.

Here is an example from another common scam:

[image]

Here are some links to users who have also fallen victim to similar things:

1. [Eth stuck in a 'UniswapFrontrunBot' contract](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/144925/eth-stuck-in-a-uniswapfrontrunbot-contract)
2. [Missing Eth after sending to contract](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/134526/missing-eth-after-sending-to-contract)

Unfortunately you may have lost some money, but you learned an important lesson that should prevent you from falling victim to another scam like this one. Good luck and happy coding!

Comment: Thank you! Your shared wisdom is invaluable. Despite the financial setback, it's a lesson to guard against future scams. Best regards!