# I created a contract

Tags: solidity, contract-development, remix, scam

I might be scammed. I created a contract https://etherscan.io/address/0xbd88AEB4f037e9a8d170299BCe9466966CdD5CF1  but how can I get my funds back I am a noob and regret trying. I transfard the money, the amount increased but I want the money back. I followed this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vhkb9G2SyVw&list=WL&index=16

this is the code I used. https://pastebin.com/raw/36sPbn1b

Comment: Unfortunately, it is correct. There's nothing you could do. See this question for an explanation of how the bot works https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/134526/missing-eth-after-sending-to-contract.